# Location calculation and then assign permanently to item in perl

Tags: perl, calc

I have this calculation that calculates a location for a graphic interface, it is fully dynamic and needs to put each item in a different location. The calculation and once of assignment works perfectly, the issue I am having though is I need to assign the calculated x and y axes nyumbers permanently to each item so that I can create links between items.

This formula can initially assign the calculation and enure each item has a x and y location, the issue is, I want to set each item to the given x and y axis so that if I want to further down create a link to say item1 connects to item2, it should create the connection with a line between item1 and item2, the line part I can do, just want to find a way to keep each initially assigned x and y axes to each item.

here is how it works. I have a database which tells me which item is connected to other items as well as where they are located.

```
    Item1..........Item1_location....Item2..........Item2_location
    Router.........Storeroom1........Switch.........2nd_floor_west
    WiFi_route.....Reception.........switch.........Storeroom1
```

Ok, so on the graphical gui I will create the pre-plotted locations by doing the calculation like this.

```
    open (MYFILE, '>>Output.xml');
        $book = ReadData ("INPUT.xlsx");

        @rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows ($book->[1]);

        my $X_initial = "160"; #specify the initial x axes
        my $Y_initial = "80";  #specify initial y axes
        my $MAX_X = 1120;      #maximum pixels allowed for x axes.
        my ($cur_x, $cur_y) = ($X_initial, $Y_initial);

    foreach my $tab(@rows) {
    my @row = Spreadsheet::Read::cellrow ($book->[1], $count);
    $count++;
    push @array, $row[1], $row[3];
      }
    my %precious = ();                    # this section will deduplicate the locations
                                          # in order for each location to be created
                                          # once only, the underlying items will be assigned
    foreach (@array)                      # below them.
      {
    $precious{$_} = 1;
      }
    my @deduped = keys %precious;
        chomp(@deduped);
         foreach my $country(@deduped) {
            if($country ne '') {


    if ($cur_x > $MAX_X) {
        $cur_x = $X_initial;
        $cur_y += $Y_initial;
    }
    if ($location =~  m/NONE/i) {
                }

    else {
    push @fixed_location, $location;

    push @location_clause, ("<icon name=\"$location\" label=\"$location\" x=\"$cur_x\" y=\"$cur_y\" image="\devices.png>");

         }
        $cur_y += $Y_initial;
         }
         }
       $count = 1;
       my $start2;
       foreach $start(@location_clause) {

       my @row = Spreadsheet::Read::cellrow ($book->[1], $count);
       $count++;

       push @array, $row[3];
       print MYFILE $start;
```

please note, this is not the full script, so if you try it, it will not print propar xml. but here is what the output will look like.

```
    <methodCall>
    <method methodName="map.createOrReplaceMapVisual">
    <map name="NSA-South-Africa">
    <icon name="Storeroom1" label="Storeroom1" x="160" y="80" image="Devices.png"/>
    <icon name="2nd_floor_west" label="2nd_floor_west" x="320" y="80" image="Devices.png"/>
    <icon name="Reception" label="Reception" x="480" y="80" image="Devices.png"/>
    <map>
    </method>
    </methodCall>
```

As you can see, it deduplicates the output to not create a location more than once, it checks in both device locations as well. The x and y gets created fine.

But now I want to later create links between Storeroom1 and 2nd floor west. If I run the same calculation, it will create locations in the given order, new devices added will reorder it as well. So I want to assign each location an X and Y which can be referenced later, so it should store somehow so that If I say create a link between Reception and Storeroom one, it should know the line gets drawn from x480 y80 to x160 and y80.

I tried assigning them into an array and pushing the array, but it can only randomly select from the array, also, I need to do foreach, for another array, then call from the location array, this did not work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is a simple print of the same calculation as above whcih does not need any files, it just prints to screen.

```
     my $X_initial = "160";
     my $Y_initial = "80";
     my $MAX_X = 1120;
     my ($cur_x, $cur_y) = ($X_initial, $Y_initial);
     for (0 .. 20) {
     if ($cur_x > $MAX_X) {
        $cur_x = $X_initial;
        $cur_y += $Y_initial;
        print "\n";
     }
     print "   \t$_:$cur_x/$cur_y";
     $cur_x += $X_initial;
     }
     print "\n";
```

EDIT!!!!

Ok, I managed to get a pre-assigned method, but still have an issue.

What I did is this. changed the last section.

```
     push @test_loc, "$location, $cur_x, $cur_y";
     $cur_x += $X_initial;
           }
         }
       }

         foreach $getit(@test_loc) {
           @new_array = split /, /, $getit;
       print "Location: $new_array[0]\n X: $new_array[1]\n Y: $new_array[2]\n";
```

Now the issue still remains, I need to match location1 with location2 in order to tell the script to connect item1 with item2 and have the correct coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Perl "memorize" functions, such as http://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize.html
They trade off memory for faster execution.

Comment: thanks for the link. I did however find one way, see the edit for the actual problem

Comment: Decided to go for writing and storing ini config file rather. this way I don't store everything in memory anyway. Thanks.